# What did StackEgg want to tell me?

Tags: discussion, april-fools, stackegg

I guess StackEgg was going to tell me something, but I am having a hard time understanding *what* exactly. Probably the font chosen is a bit too small to recognise what it was going to say or I have a really  poor eyesight.

> [image]

Either way, may I know what it's saying?

Comment: Actually, the SE staff anticipated you asking this question. The answer is a response to this Meta question, and it tells the OP to waste their time somewhere else.

Comment: I am shocked. Why you people are so negative?

Comment: You should ask a question about it on Meta! :^)

Comment: @AlexisKing: Gosh, why be so rude over an April Fool's joke? Calm down, man.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Oh, hush, I'm on good terms with nicael; I was just teasing. :p

Comment: "Oh, hush" Lovely.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, but actually you are being a *bit* rude, please don't. I don't think saying "hush" is very polite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it's a well hidden advertisement to a company in Chile.

How so? Count the squares:

```
2 4 2 1
1 3 3 2
```

Or in one go: `2421-1332`

Now, this is the phone number of [SOCIEDAD INVERSIONES HIMALAYA LTDA](http://cl.ypgo.net/SOCIEDAD+INVERSIONES+HIMALAYA+LTDA.-120432722679) - so the egg actually want you to give them a call and buy their products.

Comment: *rushes to find the flag link*

Answer (score 4):

It wants to let you know that it's still in Private Beta, and as such, it desperately needs your help to get to Public Beta.

Every 20 seconds that pass a poor SE site in beta gets restarted. Don't let it restart. Help that SE network today.

Answer (score 2):

It's not supposed to say anything in fact. It's just some extra big pixels used to mimic how people draw squiggly lines to show any writing that is unknown. I agree with @Rusemaster with its supposedly translation. :-)

Comment: Wait, just a random set of words? I don't believe!